# Im trying to make this function write to port the opposite of a variable's current state. Any ideas?

Tags: c#

What I'm trying to achieve is when the ***E*** key is pressed it will either send true or false over the serial port. So if its currently true and I press ***E*** it will send false and vise versa.
This is what I have so far:

```cs
    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((int)e.KeyChar == (int)Keys.E)
            {
                writeToPortLaser();
            }
        }
        public void writeToPortLaser()
        {
            Boolean State = true;

            port.Write(State.ToString());
        }
```

I'm extremely new to C# and programming in general so go easy on me.

Comment: What's the problem then? (you could simplify the `if` condition to `e.KeyChar == (char) Keys.E`, but I don't think that would change how it works)

Comment: Hi Jack, can you elaborate your question, `So if its currently true` here it means serial port or anything else? because in first sentence you said serial port will sent `High` or `low `. Both sentences confusing me

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I edited it. Sorry about that. The problem is I dont know how to make this work. Right now if I press ***E*** then it will just write true and if I press it again it just rights true again. I want it to alternate to where everytime I press E it switches between true and false being printed.

Comment: The `State` variable won't have a "current" state. It is redefined every time you call the function and will always be `true`.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn can I create the variable outside of the function so it wont be changed everytime?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59184477/trying-to-send-a-string-over-serial-port-on-button-press-having-trouble-getting so what about this question, specifically `A couple things im having trouble with is knowing if the laser is on or off.`? the only difference here is the changed names?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Yea sorry I worded that question badly and didnt get any responses. Ill delete it. I got my problem solved now so its all good.

Comment: @JackW glad you got it solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the current state in your class:

```
class MyClass
{
    bool _state;
    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((int)e.KeyChar == (int)Keys.E)
        {
            writeToPortLaser();
        }
    }
    public void writeToPortLaser()
    {
        _state = !_state; // this toggles the state
        port.Write(_state.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you. Could you tell me or link me a guide/documentation for things like private and void and class? I didnt know you could put a variable outside of the function like that. But otherwise thanks it works great.

Comment: @JackW Just google for any C# tutorial. There are plenty outside. However this goes far bayond a single question on StackOverflow.